# Get query id with baseurl

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a single item information from the listings in wordpress. I have created the cars listing page in wordpress. I also have one singlecar.php file in template root.

Now I would like to pass cars listing item id to the single list. How I can do it?

***cars.php***

Cartitle: Manza ( will be linkable )

```
<a href="car.php?carid=1">Manza</a>
```

***car.php***

```
$_GET['carid'];
```

How to do it if i create a custom page template in wordpress?

> I need the url structure. I am querying from a custom table, named
>   wp_cars... firstly, all the listing will come to a listing page named
>   cars.php then, every listing has a single view. So, I need the url
>   structure to pass user to the single view when user will click to the
>   title.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want car.php?carid=1 to lead to? a profile page?

Comment: I need the url structure. I am querying from a custom table, named wp_cars... 

firstly, all the listing will come to a listing page named cars.php
then, every listing has a single view.

So, I need the url structure to pass user to the single view when user will click to the title.

Comment: You should point to a custom-post-type then, with a assigned template and use ./?cars&carid=<?php echo $pid; ?>. Get the post id of the car with $pid = $post->ID; in your loop.

Comment: Please, clear me the "custom-post-type", I am not so clear... I have checked this codex>>> http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit of a tangent, but can I suggest you check out the wp-mvc plugin and the associated documentation here: http://wpmvc.org/documentation/70/tutorial/

it makes it reasonably easy to create views based on lists of records in the database with links through to individual records, and allows you to easily add admin views to manage the data too.